# OpenGL viewport from -50 to 50 instead of -1 to 1

Tags: c++, opengl, 2d, viewport

Is there a simple and efficient way to make the 2D OpenGL viewport go from -50 to 50 instead of the usual -1 to 1? Or to be able to scale it by any amount?

Comment: You have to use a projection matrix.

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about OpenGL coordinates, no it must stay in the normalized [-1,1]. Make your application normalize its coordinates, i.e. (25,0) in your application is [0.5,0];

Comment: how would I go about doing this?

Comment: ok I found a solution of using glScalef, but I'm wondering if there's a better/faster method?

Comment: Yes, if you're at the point where you are writing shaders, then you can perform the scaling inside the vertex shader, from world coordinates to screen/GL coordinates.

Comment: I'm not at the point of writing shaders, is that the only way of achieving this? Is glScalef very slow?

Comment: No glScalef is fine, just keep in mind that the typical pattern is to transform world coordinates to normalized (-1 to 1) screen coordinates. For a 2D game, I imagine you won't run into performance problems either way. If you are not writing shaders, you would simply divide the world space coordinate by your view limits. i.e., the points (0,60) and (0,40) would be transformed to (0, 1.2) and (0,0.8) by dividing by your view limit of 50.